# How to validate a non form field?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to validate a non-form field in this GestureDetector widget. I want to show an error if the user does not select anything. How can I do that? Please check my widget [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Aap6.jpg).

```dart
Wrap(
  alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
  children: dayList.map(
    (day) {
      bool isSelected = false;
      if (selectedDay!.contains(day)) {
        isSelected = true;
      }
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          if (!selectedDay!.contains(day)) {
            if (selectedDay!.length < 7) {
              selectedDay!.add(day);
              setState(() {});
              print(selectedDay);
            }
          } else {
            selectedDay!
                .removeWhere((element) => element == day);
            setState(() {});
            print(selectedDay);
          }
        },
      );
    },
  ).toList(),
)
```

Comment: Can you share a picture of that error?

Comment: I want to display it like [this](https://imgur.com/a/T8VKoSV). When I click next, it should pop up error similar to starting time and ending time. Do I need to wrap it with a FormField widget?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know what I should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can add a boolean variable isValid and set it to false when the user does not select any day:

```
//Wrap for validation:
 FormField(
  validator: (value) {
    if (selectedDay!.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please select at least one day';
    }
    return null;
  },
  builder: (state) {
    return Wrap(
      alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
      children: dayList.map((day) {
        bool isSelected = false;
        if (selectedDay!.contains(day)) {
          isSelected = true;
        }
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            if (!selectedDay!.contains(day)) {
              if (selectedDay!.length < 7) {
                selectedDay!.add(day);
                state.validate();
                print(selectedDay);
              }
            } else {
              selectedDay!.removeWhere((element) => element == day);
              state.validate();
              print(selectedDay);
            }
          },
          child: DayWidget(day: day, isSelected: isSelected),
        );
      }).toList(),
       
  ),

    Text(
      state.errorText,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
    ),

    // Show the error message if the user does not select anything
    Visibility(
      visible: !isValid,
      child: Text('Please select at least one day'),
    ),
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Would it be possible to wrap it in FormField() so that I can use the validator? So that when the user Submits the empty form, it will show an error and won't let the user move on to the next step.

Comment: Ya sure, see updated answer like that?

Comment: Working perfectly. Appreciate your answer!